# $.ajax() post json data type

Tags: javascript, jquery

That is my function, for exp.:

```
adId = 1, adTitle = test

function deleteAd(adId, adTitle) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            adId : adId,
            adTitle: adTitle
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

That is ajax.php:

```
echo $_POST['adId']; echo $_POST['adTitle'];
```

But echo only adId, don't have adTitle.

I try this:

```
   data: {
            adId : adId,
            adTitle: "test"
        },
```

And don't have result too. With HttpFox I found this post and postdata is: adId=1&&adTitle=test

Answer (score 2):

If your variable `test === undefined` then it will **not** get posted to your PHP script therefore you will **not** see it on the server side.

---

If `test` is an empty string than you just might not be seeing it on the client due to it not having any visible length.

Try doing: `var_dump($_POST['adTitle']);`

Comment: @minitech no empty string should be fine, but yes true, The OP should be using `var_dump()`

Comment: @minitech I added that to my post.

Comment: I try var_dump but alert don't appear.

Comment: @Defense `alert`? what the fruit loop are you talking about?

Comment: @Defense what gave you the impression that it would?!

Comment: Idk why but, when I try echo $_POST['adId'] echo 1, but when try var_dump($_POST['adId']) don't do nothing